# how to add bounty to new question

Tags: feature-request, hidden-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

the bounty feature is not active if a question is newly asked.

**question**
Is it possible to add a bounty to a question i have just asked(as compared to a question that has lasted some time)

Comment: No, you must wait for 2 days minimum

Answer (score 2):

[From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

> - Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.